# how to calculate time difference for each day for every employee in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, etl

i have this dataframe

```
    Matricule         DateTime        Date      Time
1   10  2022-01-06 10:59:51 2022-01-06  10:59:51
2   10  2022-01-07 08:40:09 2022-01-07  08:40:09
3   10  2022-01-26 15:39:10 2022-01-26  15:39:10
4   11  2022-01-03 14:33:38 2022-01-03  14:33:38
81  11  2022-01-04 10:04:18 2022-01-04  10:04:18
... ... ... ... ...
15  18  2022-01-24 15:51:22 2022-01-24  15:51:22
15  18  2022-01-24 15:51:29 2022-01-24  15:51:29
15  18  2022-01-24 16:54:23 2022-01-24  16:54:23
15  18  2022-01-28 14:42:01 2022-01-28  14:42:01
15  18  2022-01-28 14:42:32 2022-01-28  14:42:32
```

i want to calculate time difference between the first time of the day and last time of the day for each day for every employee to know how much hours he spent at work daily for exemple

```
Matricule          Date  WorkTime      
1   10     2022-01-06  1
2   10     2022-01-07  3
3   10     2022-01-26  5
4   11     2022-01-03  2
81  11     2022-01-04  8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the split-apply-combine approach, write a func for each group and apply on the groupby:

```
grpd = df.groupby(['Matricule', 'Date'])

def get_hours(df):
    start = df['Time'].min()
    end = df['Time'].max()
    new_df = pd.DataFrame([end-start], columns=['WorkTime'])
    return new_df

grpd.apply(get_hours)
```